# Is there a way to change the calculation unit type of the part area whilst keeping the length unit type different?

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I want to change the area unit type (to cm^2) of a part in "General Properties" whilst keeping the length unit type in "Document Settings" in another type (mm).

Is this possible and if it's possible how can I change it?

[Properties - Physical tab - dialog box](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-877564AC-78CE-4216-9913-003A2DE8D698-htm.html)

The version we are using is Inventor 2016.

Comment: What do you want to do with this value? Display it in a titleblock, in a BOM?

Comment: They are used in titleblocks on the final drawings. We may use them in the BOM, too.